# BigCommerce returns variantId for simple products in /api/storefront/carts/{{cart_id}}

Tags: api, bigcommerce, bigcommerce-stencil-cli

I'm calling storefront api (`api/storefront/carts/{{cart_id}}`) from cart page.

I would like to use the lineitems available on **physicalItems**, **digitalItems**, **giftCertificates**, **customItems** available under lineItems.

Require to generate data array on template level if given product (line item) does not have variantId but API(`api/storefront/carts/{{cart_id}}`) returns `variantId`
***for all the products including simple products and those offers variants as well.***

Even given `variantId` does not exist in the product grid also.

I won't able to differentiate from API response whether a given line item is actually a simple product or products having variants.

I have attached the cart line item console as an attachment.

```
var  cartRecords = [];
fetch('/api/storefront/carts/{{cart_id}}?include=lineItems.physicalItems.options,lineItems.digitalItems.options', {credentials: 'include'})
                    .then(function (response) {
                        return response.json();
                    })
                    .then(function (cartData) {

                        if(!cartData){
                            return false;
                        }
                        
                        var cartLineItems = cartData.lineItems.physicalItems;
                        if(!cartLineItems){
                            return false;
                        }
                        for (let index=0; index < cartLineItems.length ; index++){

                            console.log(cartLineItems[index]);
                            var itemId = '';
                            if (cartLineItems[index]['options'].length) {
                                itemId = cartLineItems[index]['productId'] + '-variantid_' + cartLineItems[index]['variantId'];
                            } else {
                                itemId = cartLineItems[index]['productId'];
                            }

                            cartRecords.push({
                                'itemId': itemId,
                                'itemGroupId': cartLineItems[index]['productId'],
                            });
                        }
                    });

                    var cartLineItemsPage = {
                        'pageType': "cart",
                        'cartRecords': cartRecords
                    };
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do a graphql query to get more details on the products in the cart. I can then compare the SKU in the cart response with the SKU in the graphql product response. If they are different, then the item is a variant.

Behind the scenes, the simple products still have a single variantId. What's most important is that the consumers of your data use the same identifiers.